# How to Group an array by lengths of 10, 0-10, 11-20, etc

Tags: c#, linq, api

I'm attempting to group an array of strings by their lengths, ie 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, then sort them using Linq/C#. I was thinking that I could loop through and do an if statement to break them up into separate arrays, then put them back together into one. This has a bad feel though - like Group By is a better option, but I haven't been able to figure out how exactly.

Comment: `GroupBy(z => (z.Length - 1) / 10)`

Comment: Do the ranges overlap?  Should it be 10-20 and 21-30?

Comment: Can you give an example? Because I understand that like u just need to sort them. Grouping and merging will give you an array sorted by 10s. If you just sort them you will get the same but elements will be sorted inside 10s as well.

Comment: @Kamushek it is just any string, like ['Taco Bell', 'McDonalds', 'Pizza Hut', 'Wendys']. You may be right about the simply sorting, then I can display them how I need to by groups on the front-end.  Ack.

Comment: You need to sort by first value of the range.  So you would have to split and parse numbers to an integer, get lengths, then groups and finally sort sort by first number.

Comment: @mjwillis Simple enough! I'm going to try that also.

Answer (score 1):

with helper range array, you can group list and then sort it

```
string[] list = new[] { "12345", "12", "12", "55", "12345", "1", "22", "333" };

var range = new[] { 2, 4, 5 };
var grouppedItems = list.GroupBy(s => range.First(i => i >= s.Length));
var sortedItems = grouppedItems.OrderBy(group => group.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good ideas in the question's comments, Here I come with a solution where you would have a full control on each property while showing records on the view.

You can use desired length of interval you want, 10, 15, 20 whatever, also you will have min and max length in hand for each group to be used on view if you wanted to show the length range with each set.

```
string[] strings = new[] { "Taco Bell", "McDonalds", "Pizza Hut", "Wendys", "Dunkin' Donuts" };

int lengthRangeInterval = 10;

var groupsByLengthRange = strings.GroupBy(s => s.Length / lengthRangeInterval).Select(g =>
  new
  {
    MinLength = (g.Key * lengthRangeInterval) + 1,
    MaxLength = (g.Key * lengthRangeInterval) + lengthRangeInterval,
    Items = g.ToArray()
  }).OrderBy(g => g.MinLength).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from the question exactly what you want to sort by.  If you want to sort by the length, then here's a solution.

```
new[] { "nine char", "ten chars!", "13 characters", "14 characters!", "eight ch", "twentytwo!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "twentythree!!!!!!!!!!!!" }
.GroupBy( x => (x.Length - 1) / 10 )
.OrderBy(group => group.Key )
.Select( group => group.ToArray() );
```